# Dynamically rearranging children to fit most of them in limited space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one large div 100vw x 100vh, and inside many children divs, equal width each, but varying height, arranged into columns using flexbox wrap.

I need to rearrange them to fit best into that square space, without leaving large blank spaces at the bottom of columns. I know that such task can be ambiguous, and I don't need to find exactly best solution, nor all possibilities. Only something that would give nice approximately even result.

Comment: Yes...numerous libraries are available for this. Asking for recommendations is off topic here

Comment: You can do this without using any libraries with the use of `column-count`. I am not sure if that's what you meant by "_some proven algorithms_", but I have added this as an answer for you to have a look at.

Comment: I have also removed the last line of your question that asked about possible libraries as your question seems invalid as soon as you additionally asked for offsite resources. However, if the CSS path I have shown in my answer is too daunting, you can have a look at the [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) library for an alternative sorting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research I found out that problem I'm facing is actually Bin-packing problem, where viewport height is a container volume, element height is object volume, and I have to minimise columns number. I'm still testing different algorithms to solve it. But thats really all I had to know. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve this with CSS is using `column-count`.

The syntax looks like this:

```
.parent-container {
  -webkit-column-count: 6;
  -moz-column-count: 6;
  column-count: 6;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}
```

This will immediately sort your blocks and break them up where possible to make a nice even layout as shown below:

[image]

The problem with this is that sometimes you might have content that **can't** be broken apart to fit into two different columns.

*(In the example image above, take note of how the last block in the first column is the same colour as the first block in the second column - this is because it is the same block that has been split to fit in perfectly)*

In this instance, you will need to use `break-inside: avoid-column`s, whilst sacrificing some of your cleaner layout options by using the following CSS on the child items.

```
.parent-container > * {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
  -moz-page-break-inside:avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}
```

This will give you a layout that looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, it's not completely smooth at the end, but it has optimised the arrangement to fit nicely.

You will also most probably have to use media queries to adjust your column count based on your screen width to ensure nice smooth responsive layouts.

Something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 760px) {
    #parent-container {
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }
}
```

I've made a fiddle to show you how to implement this. You can ignore the javascript inside the fiddle, that was just written to give each block a dynamic height as well as a random background colour.

[You can see the working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/frits_steyn/k2t12sj6/)

Comment: First approach is not possible for me, because child elements cant be broken. Second one gives pretty much exact same effect as one I use right now, but I use flexbox for this. Thats not really what I need. I need some kind of algorithm to reorder children elements to better fill those empty spaces. But thank you for input.